# Can Window shape be a parallelogram

Tags: c#, wpf, window, custom-controls, shapes

I am working on a software of my own in WPF in which I need to make the shape of the Window a parallelogram. Remember, I am not talking about the normal Shape class but I want to modify the shape of the Window itself. So, please help me change the shape of the Window to a PARALLELOGRAM..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"               
    WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Template="{DynamicResource parallogram}"   >
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="parallogram" TargetType="Window">
        <Border>
            <Border.LayoutTransform>
                <SkewTransform  AngleY="20"  ></SkewTransform>
            </Border.LayoutTransform>
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Background="AliceBlue">
    <TextBox Height="35" Width="100"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

for skew transformation visit

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.skewtransform(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. By setting AngleX = -10 and AngleY = 0.5 and WindowState=Normal, I got the result I wanted. Thank you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what @Marton was trying to say was that the `Window` itself cannot be parallelogram in shape by itself, but you can hide the `Window` and display a parallelogram shape in the application background to make it look like it is the `Window`.

The problem with this is that you will have hidden the `Window`, along with all its useful `Button`s and resizable borders. However, it's not too difficult to add your own Close, Minimise and Maximise `Button`s.

Rather than explain the whole story here, may I direct you towards some online articles where it has already been explained? This first link may be where @Marton got his image background idea: [Shaped WPF Form](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88626/Shaped-WPF-Form)... ahhh, yes it was... the first result in the search.

Next, we have the [Shaped Windows in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/shaped-windows-in-wpf/) article on the C# Corner website. This one explains how to move and close the application (without the default `Button`s). Finally, we have one more in depth article that also explains a number of other facets of a custom shaped `Window`... the [Irregular Shaped Windows in WPF](http://buksbaum.us/2009/02/28/irregular-shaped-windows-in-wpf/) page on 42 Random thoughts filtered through a Babelfish site.

Comment: Once I go through the links and articles you mentioned and find useful material on them I will mark your answer